# “Which has” vs “which have”

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> In the videos and pictures which **have** surfaced online, Gowda can be seen walking barefoot in the Durbar Hall of the Rashtrapati Bhavan stopped briefly to greet PM Modi...

Why has the writer used [“have”](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.livemint.com/news/india/meet-environmentalist-tulsi-gowda-who-collected-her-padma-shri-award-barefooted/amp-11636511451651.html) instead of “has” in the above sentence?

Comment: The subject of *have* is *videos and pictures*, which is a compound of two plural nouns. The correct verb form is *have*. That's the rule: *It has*, and *they have*.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty, are you sure the expression: “In the videos and pictures which have surfaced online...” is correct?

Comment: I misspoke in my comment. The subject of *have* is the relative pronoun *which*, but the antecedent of *which* is compound and plural. That means that the form *have* is correct. The rest of the sentence, starting with *stopped*, doesn't connect with what came before.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of have is "videos and pictures", which is a compound of two plural nouns (or the subject of have is the relative pronoun *which*, but the antecedent of *which* is compound and plural). The correct verb form is have. That's the rule: It has, and they have.

Comment: Converting comment to CW